# Propel ORM three way many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, propel

I am trying to add Propel 1.7 to a legacy php project as part of a refactor. I have generated the schema.xml file, and am now adding in the many-to-many relations.

However, there is a table that encodes a three-way many to many relationship, so it has three columns as its primary key, each of which refers to a different id column in a different table.

Basically, websites are a concept defined by a country and a language.

```
ads_to_websites:
    ad_id | country_id | lang_id
```

refer to

```
ads->id
country->id
lang->id
```

Is this supported at all in Propel? I understand how to add foreign keys and primary keys to the schema.xml, but what happens when I want to do a join through the table? Can I use isCrossRef? The documentation is slightly vague, I find.

Or should I make a new table, so that we have

```
websites:
    id | country_id | lang_id
```

refering to

```
country->id
lang->id
```

and

```
ads_to_websites:
    website_id | ad_id
```

refering to

```
websites->id
ads->id
```

Which is *possible* and I think fits the data model, but a pain to implement (another project uses the same db).

Alternatively, would another ORM like Doctrine do this better?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. Are you asking if foreign key relationships are supported in Propel? If so, then yes: in your `ads_to_websites` schema definition, just add three `<foreign-key>` entries, and define each of the three columns in that table as `primaryKey="true"`.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more explicit.

Comment: Is your use case that you have a single instance of a left-hand object and you want to get its related many:many items of a type on the right (i.e. through a central cross-ref table)? I've never used an `isCrossRef` - for the above I'd just write a getter method in the left-hand class and add a Query statement in there.